# Every time I put the code to connect my DB my app canvas appear in blank. I´m using Heroku (PHP) and ClearDB

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I´m developing a Facebook app using Heroku (PHP) and ClearDB as my database. I´m using the sample provided by heroku as the base of my codes. Everything is ok until I try to connect to my DB. Every time I put the code to connect my DB as below...

"

...

```
  $dc = mysqli_connect('us-cdbr-east-03.cleardb.com' , 'XXXXXXX' , 'XXXXXX' , 'XXXXXX')

    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
```

...

"

... the canvas of my app appear in blank.

I have no idea what is wrong!

The same occur even if I do not use heroku.

Someone can give me a light about what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see the Error connecting message on the page?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your die statement to this.

```
die($mysqli_error());
```

this should lend more insight as to what the problem is.